# I need a sample map package that works with ArcGIS runtime 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-runtime, map-package

I need a sample map package that works with ArcGIS runtime 10.4.

I'm trying to develop a WPF/XAML application using the ArcGIS runtime SDK for .NET, but I've not been able to get very far because I don't have a map package to load into it.

At this point, I don't much care what map in particular, I simply need *a* map.

Our customer has sent us a .mxd with associated .gsd files, but when I try to create a map package out of it I get numerous errors: "00174 Label expression  uses VBScript, this is not support in the ArcGIS Runtime", etc.

I'd thought I'd be able to create a map in ArcGIS online to create a map package that would work with ArcGIS runtime, but when I open the map in ArcGIS desktop and try to create a map package, I get a different error: "00142 Layer's data source cannot be referenced in the ArcGIS Runtime".

Can anyone point me to a map package that will work with ArcGIS runtime 10.4? All I need is some street data, it doesn't really matter where.

Answer (score 1):

Map Packages don't work with Runtime SDK's.  The Runtime SDK's at quartz support [Mobile Map Packages](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-mobile-map-package.htm) created with ArcGIS Pro. You can import your *.mxd file into ArcGIS Pro and create a mobile map package, but you will need to use [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET Quartz](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/quartz/).